# Replacement of a negative value in df for the same value divided by two

Tags: r, function

I try to write a function that would replace a value in a vector by the same value divided by two.

```
# replacement function for a vector
rep <- function(x)
  x.half <- {abs(replace(x, which(x<0),x/2))}
```

But, I know that this function does not work properly, because if I simulate a vector with negative and positive numbers I get wrong result:

```
a <- c(1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5,11,-11,12,-12,13,-13,21,-21,25,-25)
a.rep <- rep(a)

# data frame to test 
test <- cbind(a,a.rep)
```

Also, when I apply this function to vector a, I get a warning message like this:

> Warning message:
>   In replace(x, which(x < 0), x/2) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Obviously, there is something wrong with my function.

Comment: That is a very short version of my function, which is good. But I only need to halve values that are negative, all positive values must not be changed.

Comment: `a[which(a<1)]=a[which(a<1)]/2` This will work, there is no need to write a function for this.

Comment: Just realized that it is the best and shortest answer :D Thank you @ChirayuChamoli

Comment: @mariansess Thanks for your kind comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third argument in `replace` needs to be the same length as the values being subsetted in the second.

```
## determine which values are below zero
a0 <- a < 0
## replace them with their halved values
replace(a, a0, a[a0] / 2)
 [1]   1.0  -0.5   2.0  -1.0   3.0  -1.5   4.0  -2.0   5.0  -2.5  11.0
[12]  -5.5  12.0  -6.0  13.0  -6.5  21.0 -10.5  25.0 -12.5
```

Answer (score 5):

Although the question has been answered already, I felt challenged to add an arithmetical solution.

The expression

```
(sign(a) + 3) / 4 * a
```

will return

```
# [1]   1.0  -0.5   2.0  -1.0   3.0  -1.5   4.0  -2.0   5.0  -2.5  11.0  -5.5  12.0  -6.0  13.0  -6.5
#[17]  21.0 -10.5  25.0 -12.5
```

as requested.

*How it works*

The requirement is that

- negative numbers should be multiplied by `1/2`,
- positive numbers should not be changed.

This  can be translated to

- if `sign(a) == -1` then multiply `a` by `1/2`
- if `sign(a) == +1` then multiply `a` by `1`

Now, we need to find a linear function *y = f(x) = p * x + q* which satisfies the equations

- *f(-1) = -p + q = 1/2*
- *f(1)  =  p + q = 1*.

After solving for *p* and *q* we get *f(x) = 1/4 * x + 3/4*. With *x = sign(*`a`*)*, the factor to multiply each element of `a` with is:

*1/4 * sign(*`a`*) + 3/4*

Answer (score 4):

you could use `ifelse()`:

```
half_if_neg <- function(x) {ifelse(x < 0, x / 2, x)}
#sapply(a, half_if_neg)
half_if_neg(a)
```

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorised, so need of `sapply()`

Answer (score 2):

We can also do the assignment

```
i1 <- a < 0
a[i1] <- a[i1]/2
```

---

Or using

```
pmax(a, (a*NA^(a >=0))/2, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]   1.0  -0.5   2.0  -1.0   3.0  -1.5   4.0  -2.0   5.0  -2.5  11.0 
#[12] -5.5  12.0  -6.0  13.0  -6.5  21.0 -10.5  25.0 -12.5
```

Comment: @RichScriven It is an alternative approach.  I believe your `replace` method is very original as well.

Comment: @RichScriven I don't find anybody using this in the answer.  If you are talking about the comments, sorry I didn't check the comments.  Anyway, I also added an alternative approach which is very original as wel

Comment: @RichScriven BTW, you don't think this would have any chance of a dupe, right?